# In-app restore function worked again two days later

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, restore, in-app

I'm a new beginner on stackoverflow. I've encountered a strange problem with my restore function of an in-app purchase (through Sandbox). Without having touched my code nor changing anything in iTunes, my restore function wouldn't work anymore. Strangely I still could buy an in-app product and when I would ask to restore it after deleting my app on my device, I would be asked for my login but, then, nothing... I put aside everything, meaning not touching anything, and two days after I tried again my restore function : surprisingly, then, everything worked fine ! I just don't understand what happened in meantime ?...

Comment: Please ask coding questions

Comment: This is a valid question i think, OP wants to know why such ambiguity.

Comment: I guess it had been a server problem...